# Whatsapp: add ID to contacts list and start chatting after click on share link on website

Tags: android, share, whatsapp

On a mobile friendly website in contact us section a whatsapp link to be added for the purpose to let users to start chat with specific whatsapp account (attached to the website).

Secondly the above mentioned account/ID to be added to user's contacts list automatically as well.

I have tried the following methods but didn't work for me to start chat or add contact as specified:

```
whatsapp://send?text=join%20me%20on%20TELEPHONE_NUMBER_HERE%20%3A)


href="intent://send/#Intent;scheme=whatsapp;package=com.whatsapp;s.text=test;end;"
```

or:

```
href="intent://send/#Intent;scheme=whatsapp;package=com.whatsapp;text=test;
     action=android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND; end"
```

or:

```
href="intent://send/#Intent;scheme=whatsapp;package=com.whatsapp;text=test;
      category=android.intent.category.BROWSABLE;end"
```

or

```
href="intent://send/[countrycode_without_plus][number]#Intent;scheme=smsto;package=com.whatsapp;action=android.intent.action.SENDTO;end
```

or

```
href="intent://send/4912345678#Intent;scheme=smsto;package=com.whatsapp;action=android.intent.action.SENDTO;end
```

any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this again but you have to replace
`[countrycode_without_plus]` = your complete country code along with
`[number]` = full number

```html
href="intent://send/[countrycode_without_plus][number]#Intent;scheme=smsto;package=com.whatsapp;action=android.intent.action.SENDTO;end
```

for example I'm from mexico and the country code is "52" but the complete code is "521" in my country then the 10 digits of number.

if you don't know how do you have to write your number, just add as a contact and see how whatsapp show your number.

if you have another questions, tell me.